# Where is my Java console on OS X?

Tags: macos, java

I can't find the Java console in Preferences nor in Utilities. 
Can I open the Java console from a Terminal command?

Running OS X 10.7.5 and Java version 1.6.0_65

Comment: from which program using java?

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat maddening, but the Java console won't display unless a Java application is actually running. The easiest way to get it started is to visit https://www.java.com/verify/ from the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you're opening a Runnable Jar (one which you click in finder to open), just try running it in terminal (from Spotlight search) using `java -jar /path/to/file.jar`.

If it's a Java Web Applet, you need to go into `System Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Advanced` -> `Show Console` -> `Apply`. From here, you'll need to actually run the program before the console displays, as @danorton said.

> 'The easiest way to get it started is to visit https://www.java.com/verify/ from the Firefox browser.'